# Why looping in 1 to unique value returns 1

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
Class       Identifier  Configuration   Total_individuals   Total_goals Step    1       2   3   4   5
Class       Identifier  Configuration   Total_individuals   Total_goals Step    Root    IFNE    IFNE    IFEQ    IFEQ
Class       Identifier  Configuration   Total_individuals   Total_goals Step    Root    true    false   true    false
JDayChooser d6978cda    No_Reduction    1000                208         1       0   11  11  11  11
JDayChooser d6978cda    No_Reduction    1000                208         2       0   11  11  11  11
JDayChooser d6978cda    No_Reduction    1000                208         3       0   11  11  11  11
JDayChooser d6978cda    No_Reduction    1000                208         4       0   11  11  11  11
JDayChooser d6978cda    No_Reduction    1000                208         5       0   11  11  11  11
```

The first two lines give some information that will be used later, but for now I delete them. Then I need to use a loop with the limit of the number of `Total_goals`:

```
  df <- read.csv("")
  df <- df[-c(1:2), ] #to delete the first two lines
  total_branches <- unique(df$Total_goals)
  for(j in 1:total_branches){
    print(j)
  }
```

This gives the following results:

```
[1] 208
Levels: 208 Total_goals
[1] 1
```

First of all, why is it still printing the word Total_goals in Levels although I removed the lines that contain this value? Also, why the loop does not work? it only prints 1.

Reproducible data:

```
structure(list(Class = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = c("accessories.plugins.time.JDayChooser", "Class"
), class = "factor"), Identifier = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("d6978cda", "Identifier"), class = "factor"), 
    Configuration = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Configuration", 
    "No_Reduction"), class = "factor"), Total_individuals = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1000", "Total_individuals"
    ), class = "factor"), Total_goals = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("208", "Total_goals"), class = "factor"), 
    Step = structure(c(6L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("1", 
    "2", "3", "4", "5", "Step"), class = "factor"), X1 = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "Root"), class = "factor"), 
    X2 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("11", 
    "IFNE", "true"), class = "factor"), X3 = structure(c(3L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("11", "false", "IFNE"
    ), class = "factor"), X4 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = c("11", "IFEQ", "true"), class = "factor"), 
    X5 = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("11", 
    "false", "IFEQ"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: Unclear to me: "I need to use a loop with the limit of the number of `Total_goals`"--can you put this more clearly? And also, can you include some reproducible data?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann I mean a loop that starts from 1 to the number of total goals. In the example provided, the loop should start from 1 to 208.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to both of your question is because the columns is of class `factor`.

When you do :

```
df <- df[-c(1:2), ]
```

You remove the rows but the factor levels are still there.

```
levels(df$Total_goals)
#[1] "208"         "Total_goals"
```

To get rid of that you need to use `droplevels`.

```
df <- droplevels(df[-c(1:2), ])

levels(df$Total_goals)
#[1] "208"
```

Now even if you have dropped the level `Total_goals` is still a factor. To convert to numeric do

```
df$Total_goals <- as.numeric(as.character(df$Total_goals))
```

and then run the `for` loop

```
total_branches <- unique(df$Total_goals)
for(j in 1:total_branches){
    print(j)
}
```